# Is $|\zeta(e^{ni})|\leq \log(n)$ true for $n > 19$ and how do i can show it if it is?

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

I performed some computations in [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Czeta%5Be%5E(174521i))%5D%7C)%5Cleq+log(174521)) looking at the behavior of the values of $|\zeta(e^{ni})|$ trying to predict a lower bound. I have got the following result:

For $n > 19 :|\zeta(e^{ni})|\leq \log(n)$

**My question here is:** 
Is the above result true and if it is, how can I show it?

**Note**  :$i$ is the unit imaginary part of complex number and $n$ is a positive integer

Thank you for any help

Comment: I take it $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta-function. It has a pole at $z=1$, so if $n$ is close to a multiple of $2\pi$ you'll get large values. This will happen if $n$ is the numerator of a continued fraction approximant to $2\pi$, so that's where I'd look for counterexamples.

Comment: Indeed, per @GerryMyerson 's suggestion, $n=710$ is a pretty convincing counterexample.

Comment: I rolled this back because the recent edits were screwing up the LaTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimal counterexample is $n=25$ (see the [numerical verification](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Czeta%5Be%5E(25i))%5D%7C)%5Cleq+log(25))).

Another small counterexample is $n=44$, which as suggested by Gerry Myerson comes from the approximation $2\pi \approx 44/7$.